# Install Ubuntu on Macbook (Dualboot)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mac

I am using Mac-book. But I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot.
Give some guidance so that I can install Ubuntu on my Mac book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu have a help document to install the Ubuntu on Mac-books, hope this document will helps you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

You can also follow the step available in the URL http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/ to install the Ubuntu on mac pro